# Azure HTTP function add a xml tag automatically

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, http, azure-functions

I write a C# HTTP Trigger Azure function to read a local XML file then return to caller.
When I use the code:

```
req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContentType = "application/xml";
var content = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(templatePath);
return new OkObjectResult(content);
```

Azure function automatically add line below at the top of response:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
```

If I use "text/plain", the response return exactly local xml file.

So, how can I still use "application/xml" without the extra tag?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Here what you can do is use `HttpResponseMessage` instead of the `IActionResult` which will allow you to use the `HttpResponseMessage` which helps in the creating the response with more control.
- Now we can use the `MediaTypeHeaderValue`  to set the content type header without the wrapper.

Here I am reading a test file called “test.xml”

Complete Program:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace FunctionApp6
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string g = "C:\\Users\\test\\test.xml";
            var xmlDataResult = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(g);
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(xmlDataResult);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]